# UnicodeDecodeError: reading Spanish text from .txt file

Tags: python, utf-8, special-characters, txt

I have a text file with Spanish text and the following layout on each line:

`1. de  9,999,518    65545.55`

`2. la  6,277,560    41148.59`

I want to extract the text and save it in a list. However, there are also special characters, like "á".

When I use:

```
wordlist_es = []
    with open(es_words, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
        wordlist = [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in file1]
```

I get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 804: invalid continuation byte`

Indeed, in position 804 there is an "á". How can I convert this letter anyway to a string and append it to the list, maintaining the accent?

The .txt file seems to be encoded as utf-8:

```
print(file1)

Output:
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/content/file1.TXT' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

**Edit:** I learned that accented letters are not special characters (hence the new title) and that the correct reading of the file depends on the right encoding. I should have used `latin-1`

Comment: That means the file isn't using UTF8. There are no "special characters". Most likely it was saved as Latin1/iso-8859-1. Use the correct encoding instead of `UTF-8`

Comment: They are **not special characters**. They may not be English characters, although even English uses accented characters from time to time. That file isn't UTF8. Use the correct encoding. Try `iso-8859-1`

Comment: So easy, many thanks!

Comment: The correct encoding may not be latin-1 - as you can see [here](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#e1) `0xe1` maps to `"á‎"` in a number of encodings.  If the file originated from a Windows machine it could be one of the cpxxxx encodings.  Of course if latin-1 works that's fine - but it's worth knowing there could be other candidates.

Comment: Good point. What is the best way to find out? Thanks!

Comment: @pottele The best way to find out is finding documentation of the source. Somebody created the file and they should tell you what encoding they used. But this information is often unavailable, so the second-best way is – guessing, or trial and error. The main differences between Latin-1 and the West-European CPxxxx encodings are punctuation characters like “fance quotes” (Latin-1 has none of them).